# how can i display score in other scene?

Tags: objective-c, ios7, sprite-kit

I have to show score with SKLabel in gameOverScene. how can i show score in GameOverScene Label? I am tried, please help me.

My game scene codes here. You can see all details about score in down stair.

MyScene.m

```
@interface MyScene ()<SKPhysicsContactDelegate>
@property NSUInteger score;
@end

-(void)setupUI
{
    self.score = 0;
    SKLabelNode *scoreLabel = [SKLabelNode labelNodeWithFontNamed:@"Chalkduster"];
    scoreLabel.fontColor = [SKColor redColor];
    scoreLabel.fontSize = 20.0;
    scoreLabel.text = @"SCORE: 0";
    scoreLabel.name = @"scoreLabel";
    scoreLabel.verticalAlignmentMode = SKLabelVerticalAlignmentModeCenter;
    scoreLabel.position = CGPointMake(self.size.width/2, self.size.height - scoreLabel.frame.size.height);
    [self addChild:scoreLabel];
}

-(void)adjustScoreBy:(NSUInteger)points {
    self.score += points;
    SKLabelNode* score = (SKLabelNode*)[self childNodeWithName:@"scoreLabel"];
    score.text = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"SCORE: %lu", (unsigned long)self.score];
}
- (void)gameOver
{
    GameOverScene *gameOverScene = [GameOverScene sceneWithSize:self.size];
    [self.view presentScene:gameOverScene transition:[SKTransition pushWithDirection:SKTransitionDirectionLeft duration:0.5]];
}
```

GameOverScene.h

```
@interface GameOverScene : SKScene
@property NSUInteger *score;
@end
```

GameOverScene.m

```
@implementation GameOverScene
{
SKLabelNode *scoreLabel;
}

-(id)initWithSize:(CGSize)size {
if (self = [super initWithSize:size]) {
    self.backgroundColor = [SKColor colorWithRed:1.5 green:1.0 blue:0.5 alpha:0.0];
    [self addStartButton];
    [self addRateButton];
    [self addBackButton];
    [self addScoreLabel];
}
return self;
}


-(void)addScoreLabel
{
scoreLabel = [SKLabelNode labelNodeWithFontNamed:@"Chalkduster"];
scoreLabel.text = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"SCORE: %lu", (unsigned long)self.score];
scoreLabel.position = CGPointMake(500, 50);
scoreLabel.name = @"gameOverScore";
[self addChild:scoreLabel];
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are several approaches to do this. 
You could use a singleton class to handle that.
Other option would be to create a public score property in GameOverScene, and then pass the  score value of MyScene to GameOverScene, something like this:

In GameOverScene.h add a score property

```
@interface GameOverScene : SKScene
@property NSUInteger score;
@end
```

Then in you gameOver method set the score value

```
- (void)gameOver
{
   GameOverScene *gameOverScene = [GameOverScene sceneWithSize:self.size];
   gameOverScene.score = self.score;
   [self.view presentScene:gameOverScene transition:[SKTransition pushWithDirection:SKTransitionDirectionLeft duration:0.5]];
}
```

In GameOverScene create didMoveToView

```
- (void)didMoveToView:(SKView *)view
{
   [self addScoreLabel];
}
```

Comment: Probably the points parameter in the adjustScoreBy: method is always setting score to 0. Check if you are sending the correct value to adjustScoreBy: method.

Comment: score is works i did add NSLog in -(void)gameOver it shows true score. But it didn't work in gameover screen

Comment: In which method in GameOverScene are you checking the score value? Just tried here in didMoveToView: and it work fine. If you are checking in initWithSize method, score will be 0, because it wasn't set yet.

Comment: U mean this? I edited question, u can see all details about GameOverScene

Comment: Yes, create didMoveToView: method and call addScoreLabel in it. Just edited my answer so you can see it.

Answer (score 0):

You just need a property in your next scene (target class) and call it from `(void)gameOver` (in the source class)

Add it int your target class like this

```
@property int score;
```

then use it like this in your source class

```
gameOverScene.score = self.score
```

You will use this kind of stuff a lot for when moving data around.

Comment: my score is everytime 0 in gameoverscene.

Comment: In MyScene, use break points in (void)gameOver to see if everything is properly set. Say here :
Gameoverscene *gameoverscene = scenewithsize

And here

gameoverscene.score

After the .score, check if it's storing the result. If not, our problem is in the first class. If the result is there, then it's in the second class.

Comment: i don't understand. can u show your answer in code line ?

Comment: Use the code in my first message (the answer), and then simply clic on the line number, this should add a "breakpoint". Now when you run, this will pause the app when the compiler reads this specific line. You can add as many breakpoints as you want. Once you reach the breakpoint (simply run and navigate in your app until the app reaches the breakpoint), and everything is paused, you can look up at the bottom the value of everything. Look at the value of your score (after the line as been read!). you can move one line at a time with the little arrows on top of the bottom panel

Comment: still doesn't work. I try this, GameOverScene *gameOverScene = [GameOverScene sceneWithSize:self.size];
    gameOverScene.score = self.score;
    [self runAction:[SKAction sequence:@[[SKAction waitForDuration:2], [SKAction runBlock:^{
        [self.view presentScene:gameOverScene transition:[SKTransition pushWithDirection:SKTransitionDirectionLeft duration:0.5]];
    }]]]];

Comment: Hmm, and it doesn't work when you add   gameOverScene.score = self.score;    to your     - (void)gameOver  ?